# Power Query - Remove Date Based Duplicates

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want to keep duplicate over 30 days but remove them for under 30 days. Any help would be awesome.

Data sample is shown below:

[image]

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Is it safe to assume you want to delete duplicates in the same month but not in different months? That is, can we use months rather than 30 days?

Comment: You can add some more sample data that covers all scenarios.

Comment: I'd prefer 30 days, but months would work. Thanks.